# Assign value only when key is a valid property of a type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a type, e.g.:

```
type Output = {
    fieldA?: string;
    fieldB?: string;
}
```

And I have an object, e.g.:

```
const input = { fieldA: "A", fieldB: "B", other: "C" };
```

Now I want to map the value to another object of type `Output`, so I want to loop through the object keys and assign only when the key is a valid property of type `Output`, e.g.:

```
let output: Output = {};
Object.keys(input).forEach(k => {
    if (k is keyof Output) {
        output[k] = input[k];
    }
});
```

How do you achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript types are compiled away and not available at runtime, so you can't do this directly. However, you can define the set of valid keys as a type, then use that type to define `Output` as an object whose keys are that type.

```js
type Field = 'fieldA' | 'fieldB';

type Output = Partial<Record<Field, string>>;

const input = { fieldA: "A", fieldB: "B", other: "C" };

const fields = new Set<Field>(['fieldA', 'fieldB']);

const output = Object
    .keys(input)
    .filter((k): k is Field => fields.has(k))
    .reduce(
        (output, k) => ({ ...output, [k]: input[k] }),
        {} as Output
    );
```

Notice the type predicate in `filter`: `k is Field`. It's saying that when the filter condition is true (i.e. `fields.has(k)`), then `k` is a `Field`. This means that the `k` in `reduce` will be of type `field` instead of `string`.

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly advise you to initialize `output` with some properties defined in `Output` type. So I would approach your scenario this way:

```
interface Output{
    fieldA?: string;
    fieldB?: string;
}

let input = {
    fieldA : "One",
    fieldB : "Two",
    fieldC : "Three"
};

let output: Output = {
    fieldA: null,
    fieldB: null
};

Object.keys(output).forEach((key)=>
{
    output[key] = input[key];
});

console.log(output );
```

This way `output` will hold the properties. Imagine a case where `input` has not properties that exist in `Output` type, they would return undefined. so I would rather create an object that declares those properties even prior to mapping them with the `input`.

It's also important to note how the `forEach` loop is only interested in the properties existing inside `output` of type `Output`... the rest won't be mapped.

Comment: `null` isn't compatible with `string | undefined`.

Comment: it's absolutely fine with setting empty strings `""` as default values..